# django form validation: field error not displayed

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am lost with form validation and the way to display error messages

I have a "customized" form display in my template (displayed field by field)

I need validation between 2 fields so I should use clean method
If the checkbox is ticked, text input can't be empty
I would like to bind a error message to my text field but error message is not displayed...

forms.py

```
class CreateForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["bra_00A_act"] = forms.BooleanField(label = "", required = False)
        self.fields["bra_00A_lib"] = forms.CharField(label = "", required = False)

    def clean(self):
       cleaned_data = super(CreateForm, self).clean()
       if cleaned_data["bra_00A_act"] and cleaned_data["bra_00A_lib"] == "":
           self.add_error('bra_00A_lib', "custom error message")
           raise forms.ValidationError('error')
       return cleaned_data
```

template html

```
<form id="randomization_settings_form" method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="new_parameters" type="hidden" name="parameters" value="">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <table id="table_parametrage" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Bras A</th>
                    <th>-----</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="fieldWrapper">
                            {{ form.bra_00A_act.errors }}
                            {{ form.bra_00A_act }}
                            {{ form.bra_00A_lib.errors }}
                            {{ form.bra_00A_lib }}
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").validate();
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        if ($("form").valid()) {
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I found my error: in my view, my return redirect to another page, even if validation was false...

Comment: is it validating now